# How do I access attribute data from a shapefile to make a chloropleth in react using leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, shapefile, react-leaflet

I have a react leaflet web page I am putting together where I read in a shapefile. I want to be able to map data from the attributes table connected to the shapefile. In this case I am using the [taxi zone shape](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Transportation/NYC-Taxi-Zones/d3c5-ddgc) file and let's assume i have added number of trips to the underlying attributes table for that shape file. So if the data in my shapefile looks like (number of trips per polygon):

```
zone  num_trips
1      200
2      265
...
```

I have successfully loaded a shape file but I am unsure how to access the underlying data and produce a heatmap:

**Shapefile.js**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import shp from "shpjs";

export default function Shapefile({ zipUrl }) {
  const { map } = useLeaflet();

  useEffect(() => {
    const geo = L.geoJson(
      { features: [] },
      {
        onEachFeature: function popUp(f, l) {
          var out = [];
          if (f.properties) {
            for (var key in f.properties) {
              out.push(key + ": " + f.properties[key]);
            }
            l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
          }
        }
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    shp(zipUrl).then(function (data) {
      geo.addData(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

**Leaf.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import HeatmapLayer from 'react-leaflet-heatmap-layer';
import classes from './leaf.module.css'
import Shapefile from './Shapefile'
import zipUrl from "./assets/zones.zip";

class Leaf extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
          <Map  
                center={[40.7510, -73.9688]}
                zoom={13} style={{ height: "100vh" }} 
                //ref={mapRef}
            >
          <TileLayer
            url='http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
          <Shapefile zipUrl={zipUrl} />
        </Map>
    
    
        );
    }
}

export default Leaf;
```

`Leaf` is then rendered in `App.js`.

How can I access the data in the Shapefile component to map the values for num_trips to each zone? The values are being accessed here for the popup:

```
 {
        onEachFeature: function popUp(f, l) {
          var out = [];
          if (f.properties) {
            for (var key in f.properties) {
              out.push(key + ": " + f.properties[key]);
            }
            l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
          }
```

Comment: So you want to include extra data in the geojson properties to be displayed on the popup? Did I get it correct?

Comment: actually I am looking to map one of the properties to its specific polygon essentially making a chloropleth.

Comment: I don't get you. What do you mean "map one of the properties to its specific polygon"? And where does the file with zone  num_trips come from? I don't see it anywhere in the code to be imported. If the data is on  the shapefile you already havethem when you loop inside `onEachFeature`